# Do I have to call addSubview after calling addChildViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a container view controller using `iOS5` and new methods like `addChildViewController`.

Do I have to call `addSubview` after calling `addChildViewController`?

Do I have to call `removeFromSuperview` before calling `removeChildViewController`?

I don't see anything about this in Apple docs.
What do you think?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Short answer: "Yes, and yes."  The view hierarchy and the view *controller* hierarchy are still independent.  The containment API simply allows views from other controllers to present themselves within a parent controller's view in a clean and consistent way.

You can find a bit in [Apple's docs here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907234735/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10)... this is a relevant passage from the "Container View Controllers Arrange Content of Other View Controllers" section:

> A container manages a view hierarchy just as other view controllers do. A container can also add the views of any of its children into its view hierarchy. The container decides when such a view is added and how it should be sized to fit the container’s view hierarchy, but otherwise the child view controller remains responsible for the view and its subviews.

If you have access, I would highly recommend checking out the WWDC 2011 video entitled "Implementing UIViewController Containment" ([download it from Apple Developer Video Archive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I destroy the container, do I have also to call removeViewFromSuperview? Or even removeChildViewController?

Comment: Your quote of Apple's doc can only be found on archive.org. You may want to replace it with a newer quote from [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html), [2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) or [3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller).

Answer (score 84):

**1) Do I have to call addSubview after calling addChildViewController?**

Yes

**2) Do I have to call removeFromSuperview before calling removeChildViewController?**

Not quite

You should call `removeFromParentViewController:` instead of `removeChildViewController:`
You should also call `willMoveToParentViewController:`

For adding / removing, you can refer to this great category :

[UIViewController + Container](https://github.com/xelvenone/UIViewController--Container-)

```
- (void)containerAddChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController {

    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (void)containerRemoveChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController {

    [childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [childViewController removeFromParentViewController];

}
```

[Official resource at developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW12)

Comment: Very useful that category. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Peter-Lapisu, why don't you call `[childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self]` in the containerAddChildViewContoller method?

Comment: based on this resource, you should not call willMoveToParentViewController:self when INSERTING https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6

Comment: Regarding "You should also call `willMoveToParentViewController`": note that `willMoveToParentViewController` is automatically called in `addChildViewController`. See the [Discussion section](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621381-willmovetoparentviewcontroller)

Comment: @bunkerdive thats ok, but it's not called on removeFromParentViewController or removeFromSuperview so you have to call it by yourself when removing

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Peter's answer:
one reason I found for calling `addChildViewController` before `addSubview` was that when `addSubview` is called then the `viewDidLoad` of the child get's called, and in some cases you will want to have the parent-child hierarchy properly set up at that point. If that isn't done, during child's the viewDidLoad the parentViewController property will be nil.

Answer (score 0):

The below is an example provided by Apple documentation.

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content {
   [self addChildViewController:content];
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController];
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

You can also go through the detailed explanation given here -
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

This will give you idea about child and parent view controller relations and how to work with them.