# Xcode: How do I access methods from Sub Classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, oop

When I try to access a method in my main ViewController from a SubView, my app crashes.

Please help.

I have a UIButton in my main ViewController that changes the text in a UILabel, which is also in my main View. I have a UIButton in a SubView that is supposed to change the string again, by accessing the same method from the main ViewController. But the app crashes.

Here's my code:

Main ViewController

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SubViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *mainClassButton;

- (void) setLabelTo:(NSString *)copy;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize label;
@synthesize mainClassButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
    self.label.text = @"Let's Go Mets!";
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    mainClassButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    mainClassButton.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 70.0, 200.0, 30.0);
    [mainClassButton setTitle:@"Main Class Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [mainClassButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:mainClassButton];

    SubViewController *subViewController = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    subViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:subViewController.view];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.mainClassButton];
}

- (IBAction)touchAction:(UIButton *) sender
{
    [self setLabelTo:@"Here we go Yankess!"];
}

- (void) setLabelTo:(NSString *)copy
{
    self.label.text = copy;
}
```

Sub ViewController

SubViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SubViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *subClassButton;

@end
```

SubViewController.m

```
@implementation SubViewController

@synthesize subClassButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    subClassButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    subClassButton.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 115.0, 200.0, 30.0);
    [subClassButton setTitle:@"Sub Class Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [subClassButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:subClassButton];

}

- (IBAction)touchAction:(UIButton *) sender
{
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    [vc setLabelTo:@"If you ask me, I prefer the White Sox."];
}
```

I'm still kind of new to Xcode and Objective-C and I would appreciate any help you could offer.

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the console output so we can see the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `-setLabelTo` on your already existing instance of `ViewController` from within `-[SubViewController touchAction:]`--at the moment, you are creating a new instance of `ViewController` and calling `-setLabelTo:` on that new instance.

In order to call `-setLabelTo` on the `ViewController`, we need a reference to that `ViewController`.

`UIViewController` provides a property `parentViewController` which, under ideal circumstances, would provide your `SubViewController` a reference to your `ViewController`.  However, in this case, it does not provide such a reference.  You add your `SubViewController`'s view as a subview of your `ViewController`, but you do *not* add your `SubViewController` as a child view controller of your `ViewController`.  (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143903/do-i-have-to-call-addsubview-after-calling-addchildviewcontroller) and [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146060/1052673).)  To fix this issue, in `-[ViewController viewDidLoad]`, add the line

```
[self addChildViewController:subViewController];
```

after

```
SubViewController *subViewController = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
```

giving you

```
SubViewController *subViewController = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:subViewController];
subViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:subViewController.view];
```

At this point, your `SubViewController` is a child view controller of `ViewController` and your `SubViewController`'s view is a subview of your `ViewController`'s view.

At this point, you can change your implementation of `-[SubViewController touchAction:]` to

```
- (IBAction)touchAction:(UIButton *) sender
{
    ViewController *vc = self.parentViewController;

    [vc setLabelTo:@"If you ask me, I prefer the White Sox."];
}
```

Which will call `-setLabelTo:` on your original `ViewController` rather than creating a new instance and causing a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the parent view controller for the subviewcontroller: `self.parentViewController`  What you've done in touchAction in your subViewController is create a new View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vc setLabelTo:@"If you ask me, I prefer the White Sox."];
```

You are instantiating ViewController, but the `viewDidLoad` is not called. There you instantiate UILabel which you want to set the title on using `setLabelTo` method.

The viewDidXXXX and viewWillXXXX are called automatically when they are used in  `Storyboard` or in some UINavigationController.