# Can not add a ChildViewController in Current Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, childviewcontroller

I took 2 `UIViewController` HomeView and ViewMyStuff in Storyboard.

I am adding ViewMyStuff Controller in HomeView. In HomeView's `ViewDidLoad`, written below in my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ViewMyStuff *vwMyStuff = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewreportvc"];
    [self addChildViewController: vwMyStuff];
    [vwMyStuff didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

vwMyStuff controller is not added in `HomeViewController`. Is there anything I missing? Please help

Thanks.

Comment: What is your issue? And what you want to do which you are not able to get?

Comment: vwMyStuff is not added in HomeView

Comment: Have you checked the value of `vwMyStuff ` object while debugging?

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143903/do-i-have-to-call-addsubview-after-calling-addchildviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `subView` of your `ViewMyStuff *vwMyStuff` viewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        ViewMyStuff *vwMyStuff = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewreportvc"];
        [self addChildViewController: vwMyStuff];
        [vwMyStuff didMoveToParentViewController: self];
        [self.view addSubview:vwMyStuff.view];
    }
```

Hope it works for you!!

Comment: @ManishPatel :) Most WC.